# How to get unique key and value from map-reduce program?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

From the reducer, I am getting the following output.

```
key     value
1       apple
2       apple
3       apple
4       orange
5       orange
```

But,I need the following output:

```
key     value
1       apple
4       orange
```

Whats the correct way of implementing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

This image shows the word count flow.

You can implement through the following ways:

1.**Pig script** (Internally generates a map reduce job ) For non java Developers
you need to install pig.

You need to have your input file in HDFS.

Then use the following code in grunt shell or Hue (whatever option you have)

```
lines = LOAD 'path of input file' AS (line:chararray);

words = FOREACH lines GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) as word;

grouped = GROUP words BY word;

wordcount = FOREACH grouped GENERATE group, COUNT(words);

DUMP wordcount;
```

2. **Map Reduce Coding** For Java Developers
   You will have to use Map Reduce Api with java

Refer this tutorial.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html